# Accessing not defined property on svelte component should raise TypeScript type error

Tags: typescript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

When using Svelte with TypeScript, I expected that accessing a property on a component that has not been defined to result in a type error. It results in the property being typed as `any` instead.

I have this example code at hand:

myComponent.svelte

```js
<script lang="ts">
    export function doSomething(input: string) {
        return input;
    }
</script>

<p>Text</p>
```

myOtherComponent.svelte

```js
<script lang="ts">
    import MyComponent from './MyComponent.svelte';
    let myComponent: MyComponent;
    function someFunction() {
        const myStringReturn = myComponent.doSomething('some-string'); // myStringReturn is correctly typed as string
        myComponent.somethingNotDefined; // somethingNotDefined is typed as any. Instead, I'd like to see a TypeScript error like: Property somethingNotDefined does not exist on type MyComponent
    }
</script>

<MyComponent bind:this={myComponent}></MyComponent>
```

In `myOtherComponent.svelte` `myComponent.doSomething` is correctly typed. However `myComponent.somethingNotDefined` is of type any. Instead, I'd like to see a type error raised by TypeScript here.

Is this possible to achieve somehow? Can I add some kind of TypeScript compiler flag to issue an error in this case? Or can I perhaps use a different type for `myComponent`? I tried using `ComponentType<{doSomething: (a: string) => string}>`, but that did not work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. It's pretty simple. Instead of using the `MyComponent` as a type for myComponent, I can just define it's type as an object: `{ doSomething: (a: string) => string }`

```js
<script lang="ts">
    import MyComponent from './MyComponent.svelte';
    let myComponent: { doSomething: (a: string) => string };
    function someFunction() {
        const myStringReturn = myComponent.doSomething('some-string'); // myStringReturn is correctly typed as string
        myComponent.somethingNotDefined; // this is now a type error, as expected.
    }
</script>

<MyComponent bind:this={myComponent}></MyComponent>
```